# Redirect requests for root, serve all others

Tags: mod-rewrite

It seems like this is the inverse of most of the questions along these lines.

This is in an htaccess file.

I would like to redirect all requests for the root of my site and serve all other requests normally. So, requests for `mysite.tld` (or `mysite.tld/index.xxxx`) would go to `myothersite.tld` and requests for `mysite.tld/dir` (or even `mysite.tld/file.xxxx`) would be served normally.

I would like to serve custom error pages, as well, if possible.
I've tried a couple of approaches:

```
#This one wouldn't trap 404s anyway.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://myothersite.tld [L,R=301]
```

And this one:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.tld
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://myothersite.tld [L,R=301]
```

But these aren't doing what I want.

Thanks!

Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.tld
RewriteRule ^$ http://myothersite.tld [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.tld
RewriteRule ^index\.(html|php|htm)$ http://myothersite.tld [L,R=301]
```

If this is in your server or vhost config, change the regular expressions to include a leading slash: `^/$`, `^/index`.

Comment: Jon Lin: That worked perfectly! So far! Until my users throw another wrench in the works!